# Extjs 4.2 DirectSubmit not working

Tags: extjs, ext-direct

I'm trying to submit a form using the DirectSubmit API in extjs 4.2.

The error message is:

TypeError: me.form.api.submit is not a function
[Break On This Error]

me.form.api.submit(formInfo.formEl, callback, me);

The exactly same code works in Extjs 4.1.1

I've noticed the code (directsubmit) has changed in 4.2

Is this a bug? Has someone had the same problem?

My code:

Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

```
height: 250,
width: 400,
bodyPadding: 10,
title: 'My Form'

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.initialConfig = Ext.apply({
        api: {
submit: 'Actions.Verbis_Processo.update'},
        standardSubmit: false
    }, me.initialConfig);

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        api: {
submit: 'Actions.Verbis_Processo.update'},
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                anchor: '100%',
                fieldLabel: 'Label'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function(button, event) {
                    button.up('form').getForm().submit();
                },
                text: 'MyButton'
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

I have the @formhandler in the extdirect config.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and it is going to be fixed in 4.2.1.